# Chaning the ssh_configure file context

Tags: permissions, ssh

I tried to run my jar file on server with following command

```
java -Jar file.jar
```

I often get **write fialed: broken pipe**  if  my client computer go sleep and resume later.

I want to solve this problem based on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127369/how-to-prevent-write-failed-broken-pipe-on-ssh-connection). But, the ssh_configure file has read only permission and I cannot save the following line in it.

```
Host *
ServerAliveInterval 120
```

I want to know how can I change the context of this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save this in the per user `ssh` client configuration file `~/.ssh/config`. You need to create it if it does not exist already. Now add the following:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 120
```

Change the interval if you want but don't give a high value.

The global `ssh` client configuration file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` has the following permission:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1720 Jun  8 00:23 /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

As you can see you need to be `root` to edit the file.

Comment: I have a ssh_config file in the address /etc/ssh but I have not a root access. Is there other way to do this change

Comment: @user3487667 you don't need `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`..create the file `/home/user/.ssh/config`.. replace user with your actual username..it can be made short as `~/.ssh/config` as `~` means /home/user....now follow my answer and put the mentioned lines in the file..

Comment: what do you mean by **.ssh** and after I create this file what should I do?

Comment: `~` is `/home/user`, `.ssh` is a directory under `~`, `config` is a file under `.ssh`..so the fil to modify is `~/.ssh/config` ....create the directory `~/.ssh` first (if not exist already) by `mkdir ~/.ssh` ....then create the file `touch ~/.ssh/config` .....now open the file with your favorite text editor and add the lines i have mentioned in the answer..

Comment: Sorry I am not familier with Ubuntu  enviroment. I followed your answere but I confuse

Comment: Just run the command `printf 'host *\n    ServerAliveInterval 120\n' >>~/.ssh/config` ....this will do.....