# How to avoid Broken Pipe error from client side?

Tags: ssh, openssh

How do I prevent the Broken Pipe error from the client side of the `ssh` connection on ubuntu?

Let's say that `slurm` is running on the server and I just made a `salloc` request. If the connection is broken, recovering the session (with, say `screen`) won't do anything to the fact that my `salloc` command has been canceled by `slurm`. I would now have to start another queue. Is there a way to prevent a broken pipe on the client side, given that editing the `.ssh/config` file, while mitigating the risk, gives no guarantees?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent "Write Failed: broken pipe" on SSH connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127369/how-to-prevent-write-failed-broken-pipe-on-ssh-connection)

Comment: Hello, two great answers are proposed in that question, one is editing the config file, unfortunately it does nothing to the server's own ability to disconnect after a period of inactivity, even tho it does mitigate the risk. The other answer suggests the screen utility that, while great, it doesn

Comment: 't look like  prevention method, more like a recovery one. What is in my own answer does prevent the connection to time out =)

Comment: Let me expand, let's say that slurm is running on the server and I just made a salloc request. If the connection is broken, recovering the session won't do anything to the fact that my salloc command has been canceled by slurm. I would now have to start another queue =( , so if I understood the point of ```screen``` correctly, and the fact that editing the config file gives no guarantees, this option (in my answer) looks quite solid

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with slurm, but why would it cancel the command if your screen session is still running? It has no way to see you're not there.

Comment: Unfortunately it can after a brief period of time, we are really talking about a few seconds in my personal experience. Of course this will either depend on slurm's settings or directly on ssh, I'm not sure. I can tell that it does hold up a little bit via ```squeue --me``` command, however it never lasts long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the well known Client side solution, that unfortunately doesn't prevent the Server from closing the connection after a certain period of inactivity, that is including something on the lines of

```
ServerAliveInterval 30
ServerAliveCountMax 240000000
```

in the

```
/home/username/.ssh/config
```

file and restarting `sudo systemctl restart ssh`, I've found that the following works wonderfully. By using `xdotool`

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xdotool
```

one can write a `no_more_broken_pipes.sh` file that contains something on the lines of

```
NBP() {
while true
do
        sleep 10
        xdotool key Return
done
}
```

When ran, that is

```
source no_more_broken_pipes.sh
NBP
```

it will press Return every ten seconds, ***regardless of what you are doing***, until you abort it with `ctrl+c`.

As long as you are focused on the right terminal, the server will receive inputs every ten seconds (`sleep 10`), so the connection won't be terminated, even if you go on vacation. If using the return key is not a good idea, the `xev` tool will help determine what to write on the command so that a safer key is pressed.

***Cautionary tale***

While doing this, you should also ***prevent any pop-up window (of any kind) to appear***. I'm including log-in screens (such as `i3lock`), available update messages, whatnots. What works incredibly well for me, as long as ***just one terminal is involved***, is the *full screen* of `i3` (usually `Super_L+f`): it automatically prevents (so far it has been this way for me) the focus on new windows.

Comment: This hack gets my +1 on creativity but also blew my [WCGW](https://slang.net/meaning/wcgw) detector. Have you tested what happens if the Enter key events are sent to your lock screen? Or to the comment box on AskUb

Comment: So, for instance, for i3lock it would keep sending empty passwords I believe, I can test it on a virtual machine if you wish, but I have no reason to believe that the lock screen would be exempt. I do remark ***regardless of what you are doing***, given that unwanted Return commands can cause trouble if, for instance, you forget that this measure is in place. I see why it blew your WCGW detector =)